# What security group settings are needed to `git clone ...` on an EC2 instance?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

From my Mac, I can [run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html):

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo my-demo-repo
```

just fine, after running `ssh-keygen` and uploading the public key, as described in the URL above.

Doing the same from an EC2 linux instance fails with:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Yet I have the impression that the problem is not a rejection from CodeCommit's side, but insufficient permissions on the EC2 security group side. Those are set to:

[image: inbound of security group]

[image: outbound of security group]

Are ssh-from-anywhere and anything-to-anywhere not sufficient? (Git underneath does use `ssh`, no?) What else should I do to be able to `git clone ..` on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Your problem is a public key problem. CodeCommit is rejecting the key pair that you are using. Did you create the ~/.ssh/config file for CodeCommit on your EC2 instance?

Comment: Run `ssh -v git@github.com` and you''ll understand what is missing. Once you know what's missing, [this](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) will help

Comment: @JohnHanley That was one of two problems (Thanks!). (I see I ought to have taken a bit of time off this long weekend.) But there was a second issue: The cut-and-paste business is not reliable. Triple-clicking highlighted only one of the three lines (of the public key) in the terminal, and so I click-drag-released, which probaly unwittingly introduced two CR/LF characters into the copy buffer.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Thanks. After years of unix I now have to get used to this "config" file. How does it work anyway? What if I had two git repos I needed to connect to, would I append one after the other in the same config file?

Comment: Yes, for now, that't the way I have been doing it, I keep adding on after another, it's not the best approach, but I'm trying to figure out another way as well. I tried to create project specific config files and reading them. That's something in progress.

Answer (score 0):

> After years of unix I now have to get used to this "config" file.
>   How does it work anyway?

You don't have to use it here.
Cloning a GitHub repo on an EC2 instance can work without `~/.ssh/config` file, as long as:

- your key is the default one (`~/.ssh/id_rsa)`
- your public key is correctly copied (as you commented) to GitHub
- your ssh URL is `git@github.com:me/myrepo` (or `ssh://git@github.com/me/myrepo`)